# Do the projective modules in an exact category determine the admissible epimorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

In an exact category $(\mathbf{C}, \mathcal{E})$, we define an object $P \in \mathbf{C}$ to be projective if for every admissible epimorphism $g : A \rightarrow B$
$$
   \mathbf{C}(P,A) \rightarrow \mathbf{C}(P,B)
$$
is a surjective map of abelian groups. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the class of projective objects in $(\mathbf{C},\mathcal{E})$. If, for an epimorphism $g : A \rightarrow B$,
$$
   \mathbf{C}(P,A) \rightarrow \mathbf{C}(P,B)
$$
is surjective for all $P \in \mathcal{P}$, then is $g$ an admissible epimorphism? If this doesn't hold in general, is there some natural condition on the exact category that ensures that this property holds?

Comment: I guess you need that the category has enough projectives, so for every object $X$ there exists a projective $P$ and an admissible epimorphism $P\to X$. If in your question there are no maps from a projective to $B$, then you won’t be able to say anything about $g$.

Comment: @AndrewHubery Well, if $\mathbf{C}$ is an abelian category (with the exact structure where all epimorphisms are admissible), then it's vacuously true that "every epimorphism such that ... is admissible", even if there are not enough projectives, so "enough projectives" is not a necessary condition. But maybe it's sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There are examples, even with enough projectives, where the projectives don't determine the admissible epimorphisms.

Let $\operatorname{Vect}_k$ be the abelian category of vector spaces over some field $k$, and let $\mathbf{C}=\{V\mid\dim_k(V)\neq1\}$ be the full subcategory of vector spaces that are not precisely one-dimensional.

Then $\mathbf{C}$ is closed under extensions in the abelian category $\operatorname{Vect}_k$ of all vector spaces, and so is an exact category with the exact structure inherited from $\operatorname{Vect}_k$.

It is easy to check that the epimorphisms in $\mathbf{C}$ are just the surjective maps.

The admissible epimorphisms in $\mathbf{C}$ are the epimorphisms with kernel in $\mathbf{C}$.

Clearly, every object of $\mathbf{C}$ is projective, and so $\mathbf{C}$ has enough projectives.

But a surjective map $k^3\to k^2$ is a non-admissible epimorphism in $\mathbf{C}$ such that $\mathbf{C}(P,k^3)\to\mathbf{C}(P,k^2)$ is surjective for every $P$.

This example depends in an essential way on the fact that $\mathbf{C}$ is not idempotent complete. It would be more satisfying to have an example that is.